# How to automatically close an open details tag when another detail is clicked with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, html-tag-details

## The Problem

I have a list of `detail` tags and I would like to have an opened `details` tag close when another one opens.

*I am dynamically rendering a list of `details` tags*

### Stack

I am using React and hooks

### My attempts

I set the open attribute is set with useState and updated when a `details` tag is clicked, but this does not seem to work.

Here is a link to a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-ully-9dobf?file=/src/App.js:0-484)

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const arr = [
  { name: "Jim", age: 22 },
  { name: "Sarah", age: 42 },
  { name: "Don", age: 7 }
];

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleDetails = (index) => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };
  return (
    <ul>
      {arr?.map((thing, index) => (
        <details key={index} open={open} onClick={() => toggleDetails(index)}>
          <summary>{thing.name}</summary>
          {thing.age}
        </details>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: It is working as expected in your codesandbox.

Comment: I have been working on this for a while now, so yes it does work, but I was hoping to use a more React based solution. I think I might have problems with this approach when I filter the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an "id" key as presented in your codesandbox to do the following, use **toggleDetails** to set the id of the current opened detail and then in the **open** prop check if the current object id in the array matches this of the state.

If it does, open is true, else it is false.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const arr = [
  { id: "03F03BBE", name: "Jim", age: 22 },
  { id: "D37DEF7F1E7E", name: "Julie", age: 42 },
  { id: "8D61", name: "Don", age: 7 }
];

export default function App() {
  const [openId, setOpenId] = useState('');

  const toggleDetails = (thingId) => {
    setOpenId(thingId);
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {arr?.map((thing, index) => (
        <details key={thing.id} open={openId === thing.id} onClick={() => toggleDetails(thing.id)}>
          <summary>{thing.name}</summary>
          {thing.age}
        </details>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I added `e.preventDefault()` to close a details item when you click on it and this works for me:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const faqs = [
  { id: "03F03BBE", name: "Jim", age: 22 },
  { id: "D37DEF7F1E7E", name: "Julie", age: 42 },
  { id: "8D61", name: "Don", age: 7 },
];

export default function App() {
  const [openFaqId, setOpenFaqId] = useState("");

  const clickActiveFaq = (id) => (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setOpenFaqId(id !== openFaqId ? id : "");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {faqs?.map((faq) => (
        <details
          key={faq.id}
          open={openFaqId === faq.id}
          onClick={clickActiveFaq(faq.id)}
        >
          <summary>{faq.name}</summary>
          {faq.age}
        </details>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by having more of an explanation, take a squiz at Ben's answer and note how he explains what he did to solve the problem! There's an edit button under your answer where you can have a go at improving

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is the key!

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` has a side effect when a href link is inside of details.